# How can I add subtotal and delivery details to the minicart menu in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the minicart menu on my woocommerce site I've got it showing the products in the users cart, the total and the checkout button. I would also like the menu to show the subtotal and the delivery cost.
The code to display the total is:

```
<p class="total"><strong><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></p>
```

Does anyone know how I can add the subtotal and the delivery (shipping) using woocommerce shortcodes? I've tried

```
<p class="shipping"><strong><?php _e( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping(); ?></p>
```

But that doesn't actually work.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions or answers!

Comment: You can display the Sub Total there but not Shipping Cost, as woocommerce not know where to ship the order yet, unless you are in checkout page ( thats where user tells where to ship, then only you can estimate the shipping cost )

Comment: @Sark oh right ok thank you for that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the subtotal with the code

```
<p class="subtotal"><strong><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>
```

But it will show the same price total as the call for the Total because the cost of shipping/delivery is natively calculated on the checkout page. Reason why you cannot display the delivery/shipping cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_shipping_total(); ?>
```

Reference [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#248-256).